# Check if a column name is exist in presto/hive table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, presto

A table main contains different version. A field might not existed in an older version table.
e.g mytable_1 may only contains columnA

```
columnA
a
a
c
c
```

and mytable_2 may contain an extra column called columnB

```
 columnA  columnB
    a       b
    a       k
    c       d
    c       e
```

I am trying to run sth like

```
select * from mytable_{{version}}
where 
columnA = 'a'
{IF columnB exist}
And columnB = 'b'
{endif}
```

The result will be like
if run this on mytable_1
the first two rows will be returned.
if run this on mytable_2
the first row will be returned.

How to write the query for this purpose?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also, decide if you are using Hive or Presto.  They are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically get a list of columns in the table:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'mytable_...' AND table_schema = '....'
```

It seems you want to utilize this information to issue a query with additional condition if a given column is present. To do this, you need to apply this logic within the application issuing queries to Presto, you cannot achieve this within SQL only.